# Why can't change the value from inside Jquery $.post function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the response from ajax call and save it in another value but wont work
this is my code

```
x='go'
$.post("someurl",function(data){
    x=data;
})
alert(x)//go
```

or this 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vF3K/1/)

I am looking for a solution for this problem without storing the value in any HTML container

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.post` is asynchronous - the callback will be executed later, *after* your `alert(x)` line.

Try:

```
$.post("someurl",function(data){
    x=data;
    alert(x)
})
```

(No, there's no other way around this - you'll have to restructure your code accordingly. Don't be tempted to try setting `async` to `false`, or you'll end up with bigger problems).

Comment: I want to use the value outside the callback function

Comment: The data is only available in or after the callback function, period. Your code should be structured to take that into account.

Comment: @AymanJitan event-driven programming is inevitable in javascript, might as well embrace it instead of fighting back

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript when you make this ajax call you are sending an Asynchronous call to the "someurl". This means your function continues and x remains undefined.

Solutions:

```
 $.post("someurl",function(data){
    //use your data here
});
```

or define a function outside

```
var myFunction = function (data){
  //do stuff with data
}

$.post("someurl",myFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

why first declare x as a string and then put data in the same x?
I think you should use json and have your php file parse it into json before sending back. Otherwise it just wont give a response. It will on check whether it has executed the call and that will always be "true" regardless of its succes.

Hope this helps.

BIEG