# jQuery AJAX: return value on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
        function ChatServerQuery(data_json) {

        var result = null;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'chat/backend/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data_json,
            success: function(json) {
                result = json
            }
        })

        return result

    }
```

My function that executes a request to the server. The problem is that I can not return received from the server text. I do not know how to take from an anonymous function (event success) to ChatServerQuery (where you can easily get it back).

Comment: I answered something similar earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054897/why-cant-change-the-value-from-inside-jquery-post-function-javascript/9054910

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin That is my function completes before start the event? If I disable asynchronous, then it will work?

Comment: Yes, but that's the wrong approach (disabling `async` _will_ cause problems). You should understand that the data isn't available until your callback is executed, and write your code accordingly.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin The only problem is that I need to change the logic of the code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd better change your approach to reflect an asynchronous nature of AJAX request.

#### Using callback function

```
function ChatServerQuery(data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url:  'chat/backend/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: callback
    });
}
```

Then you would use it:

```
ChatServerQuery(dataObject, function(data) {
    // work with your data came from server
});
```

#### Using promise object

`$.fn.ajax` returns object implementing [Promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) iterface, so you can use it like this:

```
function ChatServerQuery(data) {
    return $.ajax({
        url:  'chat/backend/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data
    });
}

ChatServerQuery(dataObject).done(function(data) {
    // work with your data came from server
});
```

This option offers you more flexibility.

Comment: That's more like it! Upvoted for not suggesting `async: false` :-)

Comment: Thank you. Good variant, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

I answered something similar earlier:

- [Why can't change the value from inside Jquery $.post function (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054897/why-cant-change-the-value-from-inside-jquery-post-function-javascript/9054910)

Your function returns `result` long before the AJAX callback executes. Anything that depends on the result of the request *has* to happen in or after the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to assign `json` to `result` in the success handler, do your logic there (or in functions called from it). Or if you need to wait for the response, follow the other comments.

Answer (score 0):

function ChatServerQuery(url,data) {

```
return $.ajax({ type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    async:false,
    success: function(status){
    }
}).responseText;
```

}

//Now you will get the response text from server side via ajax call

Answer (score -2):

The request needs to be synchronous to work in this way.

Add `async: false` to the parameters object of the `ajax()` method.

Comment: You mean synchronous. It's because it's asynchronous that it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. corrected my answer. A little confusion on type.

Comment: People loves to downvote simple solutions. Instead of presenting real good solutions, if any in mind.