# Javascript / jQuery function return value empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube, jquery-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery AJAX: return value on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055810/jquery-ajax-return-value-on-success)

I am trying to load a song list from the YouTube data API and have been successful until I broke it out into it's own function.

The problem is with my local variable's value vaporizing when I return it back to the calling function.  Basically, when I try to use it, it is an empty array when it has values in it.  Does anybody know what might be happening?

```
function LoadSongList(feed){
    songList = new Array();
    $.getJSON(feed, function(data){

        if (data['feed']) {
            $.each(data['feed']['entry'], function(i, entry){
                songList.push({
                    videoID: entry.media$group.yt$videoid.$t,
                    title: entry.title.$t,
                    tumbnailUrl: entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url,
                    author: entry.author[0].name.$t
                });

            });
        }

    });
    return songList;
}
```

Comment: Can I have another hint?  I'm not sure what you mean by "A in AJAX?"  In general, I just want to build an array of structures of the title, video ID, and the author name and return it back to the calling function.

Comment: The "a" in "Ajax" stands for "Asynchronous". The `$.getJSON()` function returns immediately, before the Ajax result is received, and then your `return songList` executes quite correctly returning an empty array since it _is_ still empty at that point. Then, asynchronously but definitely after the current JS completes, the callback you provided to `$.getJSON()` will be executed and run your `$.each()` loop.

Answer (score 4):

You should provide a callback method . `$.getJSON` is asynchronous method and you are trying to return `songList` before success method get called.

```
function LoadSongList(feed, callback){
    songList = new Array();
    $.getJSON(feed, function(data){

        if (data['feed']) {
            $.each(data['feed']['entry'], function(i, entry){
                songList.push({
                    videoID: entry.media$group.yt$videoid.$t,
                    title: entry.title.$t,
                    tumbnailUrl: entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url,
                    author: entry.author[0].name.$t
                });

            });
          callback(songList);
        }
    });
}
```

Call as:

```
LoadSongList(feed, function(songList){
  // your code 

});
```

Comment: I have done little javascript programming and started looking into jQuery programming.  I am not sure I understand what a "callback" is.  Can you direct me to the right place to understand a "callbacks?  Thanks!

Comment: Move your code( after the return of LoadSongList) inside a function. and send this function reference as second arguments in  LoadSongList. following links may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483073/getting-a-better-understanding-of-callback-functions-in-javascript and http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/

Comment: second argument you pass in $.getJSON is example of callback.