# Javascript code not available when called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery AJAX: return value on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055810/jquery-ajax-return-value-on-success)

Im having this weird reference issue when im trying to get a JSON file through query:

```
    var themeData;
    $.getJSON("json/sample.js", function(data) {
                themeData = data.theme;
                        console.log(themeData.sample[0].description);
            }); 
   console.log(themeData.sample[0].description);
```

The first console.log works, the second doesnt. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the second one (chronologically in your code) that doesn't get hit.  That's because it hasn't been set yet.  The callback inside `getJSON` gets invoked asynchronously after returning from the server.

```
var themeData;

// FIRST -- themeData currently null
$.getJSON("json/sample.js", function(data) {

    // THIRD -- now themeData has a value, and gets logged
    themeData = data.theme;
    console.log(themeData.sample[0].description);
}); 

// SECOND -- themeData still null
console.log(themeData.sample[0].description);
```

If you really need to call a method "after" `getJSON`, then embrace the idea of callbacks.  Use something like this.

```
var themeData;
function myCallback(data) {
    console.log(data.sample[0].description);
}
$.getJSON("json/sample.js", function(data) {
    themeData = data.theme;
    console.log(themeData.sample[0].description);
    myCallback(themeData);
});
```

**Edit**

You could also force a synchronous call instead using `async: false` of the JQuery ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback,
  async: false
});
```

Comment: ugh, but this solution will only limit the scope to this particular callback function. I kinda need to have access to this information through out the whole document. Is there a different approach I should consider instead?

Comment: @CarlosR.Batista See my update above -- you could force it to be a synchronous call, and then your code would work.  Synchronous calls should really be used sparingly though, as they block the client script while waiting for the server.

Comment: well the thing is, im only pulling this json file once while the client will spend about 30 minutes on the same page(its a web app) flipping through all the data I already pulled. The other option would be to make an ajax call every single time I need a piece of data from this file which didnt seem too efficient to me. Im guessing async is the right call in this case right?

Comment: @CarlosR.Batista yes, sounds like it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

No, `$.getJSON` is a async method, when the second `console.log` is called, there's no `themeData` at that time.